# REACT NATIVE: How can I change the example code to function component with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How can I change the example code to function component with hooks?
In my example I want to use function component and also hooks but I am new to it and would be happy to help with this subject.
The code is an example of modals.
The code allows to perform several opening types of modals and I would like to know how to change it to a function component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';


export default class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    visibleModal: null,
  };

  _renderButton = (text, onPress) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  _renderModalContent = () => (
    <View style={styles.modalContent}>
      <Text>Hello!</Text>
      {this._renderButton('Close', () => this.setState({ visibleModal: null }))}
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this._renderButton('Default modal', () => this.setState({ visibleModal: 1 }))}
        {this._renderButton('Sliding from the sides', () => this.setState({ visibleModal: 2 }))}
        {this._renderButton('A slower modal', () => this.setState({ visibleModal: 3 }))}
        {this._renderButton('Fancy modal!', () => this.setState({ visibleModal: 4 }))}
        {this._renderButton('Bottom half modal', () => this.setState({ visibleModal: 5 }))}
        <Modal isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 1}>
          {this._renderModalContent()}
        </Modal>
        <Modal
          isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 2}
          animationIn={'slideInLeft'}
          animationOut={'slideOutRight'}
        >
          {this._renderModalContent()}
        </Modal>
        <Modal
          isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 3}
          animationInTiming={2000}
          animationOutTiming={2000}
          backdropTransitionInTiming={2000}
          backdropTransitionOutTiming={2000}
        >
          {this._renderModalContent()}
        </Modal>
        <Modal
          isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 4}
          backdropColor={'red'}
          backdropOpacity={1}
          animationIn={'zoomInDown'}
          animationOut={'zoomOutUp'}
          animationInTiming={1000}
          animationOutTiming={1000}
          backdropTransitionInTiming={1000}
          backdropTransitionOutTiming={1000}
        >
          {this._renderModalContent()}
        </Modal>
        <Modal isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 5} style={styles.bottomModal}>
          {this._renderModalContent()}
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    padding: 12,
    margin: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
  },
  modalContent: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 22,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
  },
  bottomModal: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    margin: 0,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete Functional Component Code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

const Example = () => {
  const [visibleModal, setVisibleModal] = useState(null);

  const _renderButton = (text, onPress) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  const _renderModalContent = () => (
    <View style={styles.modalContent}>
      <Text>Hello!</Text>
      {_renderButton("Close", () => setVisibleModal(null))}
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {_renderButton("Default modal", () => setVisibleModal(1))}
      {_renderButton("Sliding from the sides", () => setVisibleModal(2))}
      {_renderButton("A slower modal", () => setVisibleModal(3))}
      {_renderButton("Fancy modal!", () => setVisibleModal(4))}
      {_renderButton("Bottom half modal", () => setVisibleModal(5))}
      <Modal isVisible={visibleModal === 1}>
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        isVisible={visibleModal === 2}
        animationIn={"slideInLeft"}
        animationOut={"slideOutRight"}
      >
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        isVisible={visibleModal === 3}
        animationInTiming={2000}
        animationOutTiming={2000}
        backdropTransitionInTiming={2000}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={2000}
      >
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        isVisible={visibleModal === 4}
        backdropColor={"red"}
        backdropOpacity={1}
        animationIn={"zoomInDown"}
        animationOut={"zoomOutUp"}
        animationInTiming={1000}
        animationOutTiming={1000}
        backdropTransitionInTiming={1000}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={1000}
      >
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
      <Modal isVisible={visibleModal === 5} style={styles.bottomModal}>
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Example;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    padding: 12,
    margin: 16,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
  },
  modalContent: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 22,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
  },
  bottomModal: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    margin: 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: its works ..u just forgot this.state in "<Modal isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === 1}>"

Comment: what is the diffrents between your code and the "thedude" code ? i try to understand ..coz his code doesnt works and yours is works

Comment: The problem I see in his code is that he is passing the complete object to setVisibleModal({ visibleModal: 1 }) like this which is not correct. basically, useState provides us 3 things 1. state 2. setState function to change the state. 3. initial state. He is using visibleModal as an Int but when updating the state with setVisibleModal he is passing the object that's why his code is not working it just should be setVisibleModal(1). simple. I hope you understand now.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very simple, note the changes I made:

- no more `this`
- no more `render` function
- use of `useState`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Example() {
  const [visibleModal, setVisibleModal] = useState(null)

  _renderButton = (text, onPress) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )

  _renderModalContent = () => (
    <View style={styles.modalContent}>
      <Text>Hello!</Text>
      {_renderButton('Close', () => setVisibleModal(null))}
    </View>
  )

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {_renderButton('Default modal', () => setVisibleModal(1))}
      {_renderButton('Sliding from the sides', () => setVisibleModal(2))}
      {_renderButton('A slower modal', () => setVisibleModal(3))}
      {_renderButton('Fancy modal!', () => setVisibleModal(4))}
      {_renderButton('Bottom half modal', () => setVisibleModal(5))}
      <Modal isVisible={visibleModal === 1}>
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        isVisible={visibleModal === 2}
        animationIn={'slideInLeft'}
        animationOut={'slideOutRight'}
      >
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        isVisible={visibleModal === 3}
        animationInTiming={2000}
        animationOutTiming={2000}
        backdropTransitionInTiming={2000}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={2000}
      >
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        isVisible={visibleModal === 4}
        backdropColor={'red'}
        backdropOpacity={1}
        animationIn={'zoomInDown'}
        animationOut={'zoomOutUp'}
        animationInTiming={1000}
        animationOutTiming={1000}
        backdropTransitionInTiming={1000}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={1000}
      >
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
      <Modal isVisible={visibleModal === 5} style={styles.bottomModal}>
        {_renderModalContent()}
      </Modal>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: can u show me please working snack ? coz its not work now

Comment: What does not work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: its not open the modals .. u can see

Comment: u said "Actually, defining components in another component render function is not a good idea. I would recommend agains it" - but its not working..please send me a working snack.

Comment: try adding `import React, { useState } from "react"` at the top

Comment: it still not works..the modals doesnt opens as my example above.

Comment: Thanks @Hamas Hassan for spotting and fixing the bug. The code should now work.

Comment: Your welcome Brother. It will work now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const CompenentName = () => {

     const [visibleModal, setModalVisibility] = React.useState(null);

     const _renderButton = ({ text, onPress }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
               <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text>{text}</Text>
               </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
     );

     const _renderModalContent = () => (
          <View style={styles.modalContent}>
               <Text>Hello!</Text>
               <_renderButton text='Close' onPress={() => setModalVisibility(null)} />
          </View>
     );

     return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
               <_renderButton text='Default modal' onPress={() => setModalVisibility(1)} />
               <_renderButton text='Sliding from the sides' onPress={() => setModalVisibility(2)} />
               <_renderButton text='A slower modal' onPress={() => setModalVisibility(3)} />
               <_renderButton text='Fancy modal!' onPress={() => setModalVisibility(4)} />
               <_renderButton text='Bottom half modal' onPress={() => setModalVisibility(5)} />
               <Modal isVisible={visibleModal === 1}>
                    <_renderModalContent />
               </Modal>
               <Modal
                    isVisible={visibleModal === 2}
                    animationIn={'slideInLeft'}
                    animationOut={'slideOutRight'}
               >
                    <_renderModalContent />
               </Modal>
               <Modal
                    isVisible={visibleModal === 3}
                    animationInTiming={2000}
                    animationOutTiming={2000}
                    backdropTransitionInTiming={2000}
                    backdropTransitionOutTiming={2000}
               >
                    <_renderModalContent />
               </Modal>
               <Modal
                    isVisible={visibleModal === 4}
                    backdropColor={'red'}
                    backdropOpacity={1}
                    animationIn={'zoomInDown'}
                    animationOut={'zoomOutUp'}
                    animationInTiming={1000}
                    animationOutTiming={1000}
                    backdropTransitionInTiming={1000}
                    backdropTransitionOutTiming={1000}
               >
                    <_renderModalContent />
               </Modal>
               <Modal isVisible={visibleModal === 5} style={styles.bottomModal}>
                    <_renderModalContent />
               </Modal>
          </View>
     );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
     },
     button: {
          backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
          padding: 12,
          margin: 16,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          borderRadius: 4,
          borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
     },
     modalContent: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          padding: 22,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          borderRadius: 4,
          borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
     },
     bottomModal: {
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          margin: 0,
     },
});

export default CompenentName;
```

Comment: thedude answer is good. I saw after posting. My answer has few things different that I would recommend you to use.

Comment: Actually, defining components in another component render function is not a good idea. I would recommend agains it

Comment: but " thedude" - why your code dosnt work ? can u send a working snack ?

Comment: "defining components in another component render function is not a good idea" - I agree. Just wanted to keep the question syntax. Taking them both out (cut-paste) is easy and good idea.